# Calling 'is_valid()' removes data from the serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

When I am calling is_valid on my serializer, some of the data passed to the serializer is not getting saved. The `files` field is available in the serializer.initial_data, but does not get saved in serializer.validated_data. Any ideas?

Serializer:

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    files = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.FileField()
        )
```

And the following view:

```
class SomeView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = SomeSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        email = serializer.validated_data["email"]
        files = serializer.validated_data.get("files")
        #Do something here
        return response
```

Comment: Without seeing the full code, this could happen if you have any fields marked as `read_only` in `SomeSerializer`.

Comment: The full serializer code just has two more fields(both `CharFields`). No field in the serializer is marked `read_only`

Comment: I haven't used a `FileField` serializer before, so I'm not sure what else to suggest other than DRF thinks the list contents of `files` aren't really files.

Comment: @themanatuf Thanks. That actually gave me ideas.

Comment: It turns out that I was POST'ing data in an incorrect form to the serializer. While the list elements should have be sent in the `data[files[index]]` format in this case, I was sending it as `data[files] = [<InMemoryObject1>,<InMemoryObject2>,<InMemoryObject3> ]`